# how to play video in the background of PNG image?

Tags: jquery, css, html

I want to play a video under the background of a PNG image. For reference, you may visit [Velten Media](https://www.veltenmedia.nl/). They did it in the text. Here is my Logo

[image: Logo Image here]
How would I be able to play a video under the image? For reference video, you may take any video.

Comment: I quick google search found this: https://codepen.io/SahAssar/pen/YPWxWX

Comment: please inspect the page which you mentioned and you will get a `video` tag and using it you can set it inside your image

Comment: If you inspect the code on the Velten Media, you'll see that the effect is done with css `clip-path`

Comment: @Charlie Thanks for the pen.

Comment: @VilleKoo Yes, I also did notice that and I'll try to do like that. Thanks